# A good book on lattices

Tags: lattice-crypto

I have recently started studying lattices. The book that I am following is "Complexity of lattice problem by Shafi Goldwasser and Daniele micciancio" but it is too much inclined towards computational complexity and problems.

Can someone refer a good book from cypto perspectives and easy to understand and grasp the concepts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend Chris Peikert's survey, called [A Decade of Lattice Cryptography](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I have followed Micciancio and Goldwasser of late precisely for "crypto perspective", but my crypto perspective may be inclined more towards theory. I've not come across any other book dealing with the subject matter, but I have referred to a few courses.

Manindra Agarwal's "[Rings and Integer Lattices in Computer Science](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~denis/barbados07/barbados2007.ps)" is a good starting point if you need some algebra foundations.

Vinod Vaikuntanathan's [course](https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/COURSES/CSC2414-F11/index.html) may be what you're looking for.

Micciancio's and Oded Regev's course lecture notes may be helpful for some more perspective.